What is the result of $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2} \sin \left(\frac{n^2}{k}\right)$？
I can prove $$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2} \sin \left(\frac{n^2}{k}\right)<\frac{1}{2}$$ by $$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2} \sin \left(\frac{n^2}{k}\right)<\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2} =\frac{1}{2}$$but what should be the lower bound? I tried to build one but it seems too small: $$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2} \sin \left(\frac{n^2}{k}\right)=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin \left(\frac{n^2}{k}\right)}{\frac{n^2}{k}}>\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n1-\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{n^2}{k}\right)^2$$ I know it is wrong, so can someone give me some suggest or hint?

It could be interesting to look at  $\int_{1}^n \frac{k}{n^2} \sin \left(\frac{n^2}{k}\right),dk$

I get $\int_n^{n^2} \frac{1}{x} \sin (x) d x$ by substitution. Then I let $n \rightarrow \infty$, and it's result is $0$. Is this the right approach?

Main Result. We prove the following statement:

Theorem. Let $\alpha > 0$. Then the probability measure
$$ \mu_n := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \delta_{(\frac{k}{n}, \frac{\alpha n^2}{k} \text{ mod } 1)} \tag{1}\label{e:1} $$
converges in distribution to the uniform measure on $[0, 1]^2$. That is, for any continuous function $\phi : [0, 1]^2 \to \mathbb{C}$,
$$ \int_{[0, 1]^2} \phi(x, y) \, \mu_n(\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y)
\to \int_{[0, 1]^2} \phi(x, y) \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \tag{2}\label{e:2}$$
as $n \to \infty$.

For example, the figure below is the histogram of points of the form $(\frac{k}{n}, \frac{n^2}{2\pi k}\text{ mod } 1)$ for $n = 10^6$ and $k = 1, \ldots, n$, demonstrating that $\mu_n$ defined as in $\eqref{e:1}$ is approximately uniform for large $n$:

This theorem is relevant to our case, because the OP's sum,
$$ S_n := \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{n^2} \sin\left(\frac{n^2}{k}\right), $$
corresponds to the case where $\alpha = \frac{1}{2\pi}$ and $\phi(x, y) = x\sin(2\pi y)$, yielding
$$
\begin{align*}
S_n
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{n} \sin\left(2\pi \left(\frac{n^2}{2\pi k} \text{ mod } 1\right)\right) \\
&= \int_{[0, 1]^2} x \sin(2\pi y) \, \mu_n(\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y) \\
&\to \int_{[0, 1]^2} x \sin(2\pi y) \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
= 0.
\end{align*}
$$

Proof of Theorem. It suffices to show:

Lemma. For any $\alpha > 0$ and for any $0 < a < b \leq 1$,
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k \in (an, bn] \cap \mathbb{Z}} e^{i\alpha n^2/k} = 0. \tag{3}\label{e:3} $$

Step 1 - Proving the Lemma. We first check that this lemma implies the theorem.

Intuition (TL;DR). The lemma implies the theorem because (1) the lemma tells that the assertion of the theorem holds when $\phi$ is of the form
$$\mathbf{1}_{(a, b]}(x) e^{2\pi i p y}$$
for $0 < a < b \leq 1$ and $p \in \mathbb{Z}$, and (2) the finite linear combinations of functions of this form can approximate any continuous function on $[0, 1]^2$. The precise sense in which this approximation holds will be detailed in the course of the proof.

Indeed, then $\eqref{e:3}$ implies that, for any $p \in \mathbb{Z}$,
$$ \int \mathbf{1}_{(a, b]}(x) e^{2\pi i p y} \, \mu_n(\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y)
\to (b-a)\mathbf{1}[p = 0]
= \int \mathbf{1}_{(a, b]}(x) e^{2\pi i p y} \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y. $$
Using this and the property that the marginal distribution $\mu_n(\mathrm{d}x, [0, 1])$ converges to the uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$, it is a routine job to show that the theorem holds. We only sketch the idea:
Fix $\varepsilon > 0$, and let $N \geq 1$ be an integer large enough so that $|\phi(\mathbf{x}) - \phi(\mathbf{x}')| < \varepsilon$ whenever the two points $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}'$ in $[0, 1]$ are within the distance of $\frac{1}{N}$. Such $N$ exists because of the uniform continuity of $\phi$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
&\int_{[0, 1]^2} \phi(x, y) \, \mu_n(\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y) \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{N-1} \int_{[0, 1]^2} \mathbf{1}_{(\frac{j}{N},\frac{j+1}{N}]}(x) \phi(\tfrac{j}{N}, y) \, \mu_n(\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y) + \mathcal{O}\left(\max\left\{ \varepsilon, \frac{\sup|\phi|}{N} \right\} \right),
\end{align*}
$$
where the cost $\varepsilon$ comes from approximating $\phi$ on each strip $(\frac{j}{N},\frac{j+1}{N}] \times [0, 1]$ by the function of the form $\mathbf{1}_{(\frac{j}{N},\frac{j+1}{N}]}(x) \phi(\tfrac{j}{N}, y)$, and the cost $\frac{\sup|\phi|}{N}$ comes from absorbing the integral of $\phi$ on the last strip $[0,\frac{1}{N}]\times[0, 1]$ into the error term. Then, each integral in the second line can be further approximated by $\mathbf{1}_{(\frac{j}{N},\frac{j+1}{N}]}(x)$ times a trigonometric polynomial of $y$ using Stone–Weierstrass theorem. This approximation, in conjunction with $\eqref{e:3}$, easily implies the desired assertion of the theorem.
Step 2. It remains to prove the lemma.

Intuition (TL;DR). In doing so, we introduce a coarse-graining argument. More precisely, we show that the sum in $\eqref{e:3}$, when $k$ is localized to a "moderately small" region, becomes almost a geometric sum. This allows us to estimate those localized sums more easily, and we show that their respective bounds sum to a "small" quantity that vanishes as $n \to \infty$.

Indeed, let $0 < a < b \leq 1$, and $\alpha > 0$. By substituting $k \mapsto n-k$, we write the sum in $\eqref{e:3}$ by
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k \in (an, bn] \cap \mathbb{Z}} e^{i\alpha n^2/k}
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k \in [(1-b)n, (1-a)n) \cap \mathbb{Z}} e^{i\alpha \frac{n^2}{n-k}}.
\end{align*}
$$
Now, fix a sequence $(\Delta_n)$ of positive integers such that
$$ \Delta_n \to \infty \qquad\text{and}\qquad \frac{\Delta_n^2}{n} \to 0 $$
as $n \to \infty$. Also, define $k_0, k_1, \ldots $ and $\Delta k_j$ by
$$ k_0 = \lceil (1-b)n \rceil, \qquad k_{j+1} = \min\{ k_j + \Delta_n, \lceil (1-a)n \rceil \}, \qquad \Delta k_j = k_{j+1} - k_j. $$
Let $[\![ k_j : k_{j+1} )\!) = \mathbb{Z} \cap [k_j, k_{j+1})$ denote the set of all integers $k$ between $k_j$ and $k_{j+1}$, including $k_j$ but excluding $k_{j+1}$. Then by writing each $k \in [\![ k_j : k_{j+1} )\!)$ by $k = k_j + h$, we can verify that the following decomposition holds:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{n^2}{n-k}
&= n
+ \frac{k_j}{1 - \frac{k_j}{n} }
+ \frac{h}{(1 - \frac{k_j}{n})^2}
+ \frac{h^2}{n (1 - \frac{k_j}{n})^3(1 - \frac{h}{n - k_j})} \\
&= n
+ \frac{k_j}{1 - \frac{k_j}{n} }
+ \frac{h}{(1 - \frac{k_j}{n})^2}
+ \mathcal{O}(\frac{h^2}{n}),
\end{align*}
$$
where the implicit bound of the error term in the last line depends only on $a$. Using this, we get
$$
\begin{align*}
\left| \sum_{k \in [\![ k_j : k_{j+1} )\!)} e^{i\alpha \frac{n^2}{n-k}} \right|
&= \left| \sum_{k \in [\![ k_j : k_{j+1} )\!)} \exp\Biggl( i\alpha \Biggl( \frac{h}{(1 - k_j/n)^2}
+ \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{h^2}{n}\right) \Biggr) \Biggr) \right| \\
&\leq \left| \sum_{h = 0}^{\Delta k_j - 1} \exp\Biggl(i\alpha \frac{h}{(1 - k_j/n)^2}\Biggr) \right| + \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{\Delta_n^2 \Delta k_j}{n} \right) \\
&\leq \min\left\{ \frac{2}{\left|1 - e^{i\alpha / (1 - k_j/n)^2} \right|}, \Delta k_j \right\} + \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{\Delta_n^2 \Delta k_j}{n} \right).
\end{align*}
$$
Summing this for $j$ for which $k_j < k_{j+1}$,
$$
\begin{align*}
&\left| \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k \in [(1-b)n, (1-a)n) \cap \mathbb{Z}} e^{i\alpha \frac{n^2}{n-k}} \right| \\
&\leq \sum_j \min\left\{ \frac{2}{\Delta k_j \left|1 - e^{i\alpha / (1 - k_j/n)^2} \right|}, 1 \right\} \frac{\Delta k_j}{n}  + \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{\Delta_n^2}{n} \right) \\
&\leq \int_{0}^{b-a} \min\left\{ \frac{2}{\Delta_n \left|1 - e^{i\alpha / (b - x + \mathcal{O}(\Delta_n/n))^2} \right|}, 1 \right\} \, \mathrm{d}x  + \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{\Delta_n^2}{n} \right).
\end{align*}
$$
Now by the dominated convergence theorem, as $n \to \infty$, this bound converges to $0$. Therefore the desired claim follows. $\square$

A Conjecture. It seems that a much stronger assertion holds for $S_n$:

Conjecture. $S_n = \mathcal{O}(n^{-1/2})$.

Indeed, the following numerical simulation, computing the values of $\sqrt{n}S_n$ for $n = 1, \ldots, 10^4$, hints that this is likely true:


These are really some cool graphix from a white cat.

Genius idea indeed! It had never occurred to me that we could use Lebesgue integrals to think about this problem

edit: apologies, I didn't see the bit where you specified that you would only like a hint
hint: examine the coefficient $\frac{k}{n^2}$ and consider the behaviour of sine
consider evaluating before seeing my solution

Evaluating the limit$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2} \sin \left(\frac{n^2}{k}\right)$$
Let us denote the sum as $S_n$:
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2} \sin \left(\frac{n^2}{k}\right)$$ to find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n$.
Let us observe the general term of the sum
$$s_k=\frac{k}{n^2}\sin\left(\frac{n^2}{k}\right)$$ to examine how $s_k$ behaves for different values of $k$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Recall that the argument of the sine function is:
$$\theta_k=\frac{n^2}{k}$$
As $n\rightarrow\infty$

For small $k$ (i.e., $k$ is fixed when $n$ grows), $\theta_k$ becomes very large
For $k=n$, $\theta_n=n^2/n=n$ which also becomes large

Thus for all $k$ in the range $1\le k\le n$, $\theta_k$ grows without bound.
The sine function is periodic and bounded between $-1$ and $1$, as is obvious. For large $\theta$, $\sin(\theta)$ oscillates rapidly which means the ppsitive and negative values tend to cancel out on average.
The magnitude of each term $s_k$ is:
$$|s_k|=\left|\frac{k}{n^2}\sin\left(\frac{n^2}{k}\right)\right|\le\frac{k}{n^2}$$
since $\sin(\theta)$ is bounded by $1$. Now for the sum of the magnitudes,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n|s_k|\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n+1}{2n}$$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$ the sum approaches $\frac{1}{2}$ meaning the total magnitude of the terms is bounded and does not grow without limit.
Due to oscillatory nature of the sine function the positive and negative terms tend to cancel each other out. The values of $\sin\left(\frac{n^2}{k}\right)$ for different $k$ are effectively random in the interval $[-1,1]$ as $n^2/k$ varies over a large range and $\sin(\theta)$ cycles rapidly. The average value of $\sin(\theta)$ over many periods is zero.
Hence when summing a large number of oscillating terms the overall sum tends to zero. We can support this by computing the variance of the sum.
Computing sum of the squares of the terms:
$$\sum^n_{k=1}s^2_k=\sum^n_{k=1}\left(\frac{k}{n^2}\sin\left(\frac{n^2}{k}\right)\right)^2=\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{k^2}{n^4}\sin^2\left(\frac{n^2}{k}\right)$$ Since $\sin^2(\theta)\le 1$ we have
$$\sum^n_{k=1}s^2_k\le\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{k^2}{n^4}$$
Computing upper bound
$$\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{k^2}{n^4}=\frac{1}{n^4}\sum^n_{k=1}k^2=\frac{1}{n^4}\cdot\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
$$n(n+1)(2n+1)=2n^3+3n^2+n$$
Thus
$$\sum^n_{k=1}s^2_k\le\frac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{6n^4}=\frac{2+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}{6n}\le\frac{2}{6n}=\frac{1}{3n}$$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$ the sum of the squares approaches zero. By Chebyshev's inequality, the probability that the sum deviates significantly from zero is small. The variance $\sigma^2$ of the sum $S_n$ is proportional to $\frac{1}{n}$. The standard deviation is $\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3n}}$.
Now as $n\rightarrow\infty$, $\sigma\rightarrow0$, indicating $S_n$ concentrates around its mean value (zero).
Given that individual terms $s_k$ are bounded and their magnitudes decrease with $n$, the sum of the terms exhibits cancellation due to the nature of the sine function and the variance of the sum approaching zero as $n\rightarrow\infty$, we can conclude that
$$\boxed{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n=0}$$

Your claim about asymptotic independence of $s_k$'s is too bold to be used without justification. More precisely, regarding $s_k = \sin(n^2/k)$ as random variables with respect to the uniform distribution $n\sim\mathcal{U}([![1,\ldots,N]!])$, for $N \gg 1$, how do you show that the aggregate effect of correlations between $s_k$'s is negligible compared to the contribution from the variances of $s_k$'s? Otherwise, I don't see how your estimate on $\sum_{k=1}^{n} s_k^2$ is related to $\sum_{k=1}^{n}s_k$.

Hmm yes I see the problem, thank you. Do you believe that approximating the sum by an integral would be a viable method? I'll try my best to revise in the meantime.

I am skeptical about approximating the sum by an integral, as I believe that the cancellative behavior of $\sum_k \sin(n^2/k)$ critically hinges on a delicate combination of number-theoretic properties of the sequence $n^2/k$ and the irrationality of $\pi$. But my guess might be incorrect.

I see. I'll revise an answer within a week. Moreover, your answer is most instructive - I'll try explore alternatives.

Great idea，It reminds me the topologist's sine curve
